# Saving Image found in UIImagePicker to Upload to Database

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have successfully implemented an Image Picker in my app - it pulls pictures from the library and you can select specific images.

Now after the user selects the image, I want to store the image to a variable somehow in my code so that I can upload the image to a database.

Here's what I currently have in my code:

```
 public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskCompletionSource;
        UIImagePickerController imagePicker;

        public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync()
        {
            //Create and define UIImagePickerController
            imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController
            {
                SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
                MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
            };

            //Set Event Handlers
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled += OnImagePickerCancelled;

            //Present UIImagePickerController
            UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var viewController = window.RootViewController;
            viewController.PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, null);

            //Return Task Object
            taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
            return taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

        void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
        {
            //assigns var image to the edited image if there is one, otherwise it'll assign it to the original image
            UIImage image = args.EditedImage ?? args.OriginalImage;

            if (image != null)
            {
                //Convert UIImage to .NET stream object
                NSData data;

                if(args.ReferenceUrl.PathExtension.Equals("PNG") || args.ReferenceUrl.PathExtension.Equals("png"))
                {
                    data = image.AsPNG();
                    //Console.WriteLine(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    data = image.AsJPEG(1);
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                }

                Stream stream = data.AsStream();

                UnregisterEventHandlers();
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(stream);
            }

            else
            {
                UnregisterEventHandlers();
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }

        void OnImagePickerCancelled(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            UnregisterEventHandlers();
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }

        void UnregisterEventHandlers()
        {
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia -= OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled -= OnImagePickerCancelled;
        }
```

Here is what I'm wondering:  I need to upload this image to a database with the datatype varbinary. The image currently has the datatype NSData which as I've researched is used to store items such as pictures with raw binary data. Am I storing this correctly as of right now to upload to a database? Do I need to do some sort of conversion?

Comment: You're talking about _uploading it to a database_, but your code is trying to store it in user defaults. Which is sort of database, but the _uploading_ word here doesn't make much sense. What is your goal?

Comment: And you already have it in a variable - `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)` creates `NSData` containing the JPEG representation, `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` creates the PNG representation, ...

Comment: @zrzka I apologize. Let me re-explain. My ultimate goal is to take a selected image and store it in a SQL Server database with the datatype varbinary (I'm using SQL Server). in order to do this I need to (I assume) first store the image into some sort of variable in my code (what I'm asking how to do). Uploading to a database is a separate question I can save for another time. I'm just focusing on first saving the image selected in my code (perhaps with a pointer, a variable, etc)

Comment: Let me edit my question real quick.

Comment: @zrzka I reworded my question and provided my current code

Comment: @izzykk check the answer, I just updated to final code, It should work fine what you are looking for.

Comment: @izzykk so, it's .NET (Xamarin), why did you tagged this question with `swift`?

Comment: @izzyk You don't need any other conversion. `NSData` holds binary data. Picker gives you `UIImage`, your `AsJPEG()` gives you `NSData` (with JPEG inside) and that's it. If you dump `NSData` to a file with `.jpeg` extension you'll have a proper JPEG image.

Comment: @zrzka I was using a dependency injection and the library I'm using isn't a Xamarin library - its swift - so I felt like it wasn't correct to tag it as Xamarin. Should I relabel it? I am fairly new to all of this. I'll gladly change it if it's misleading

Comment: @izzykk keep it as you're using Swift and you have a Swift answer below. It's not always black & white. Generally, the tag is something like - I'm looking for a `tag` expert - it can be OS, programming language, framework, ... This is how you attract the right person to answer your question. Another thing is that you're talking about `NSData` in your question which implies Objective-C, because the Swift language variant is `Data`, etc. Just be more precise when you're asking.

Comment: @zrzka that makes sense. does NSData not hold binary data in C#? The Microsoft Docs say that it's a class that deals with "byte buffer manipulation". It doesn't specify whether or not variables of its type are binary or can be cast to binary.

Comment: It holds binary data.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to your ViewController

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var choosenImageData: Data?

    fileprivate lazy var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [(kUTTypeImage as String)]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        return imagePicker
    }()

    @IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera // .photoLibrary
     self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.choosenImageData = image.jpeg(.lowest)
        }
    }
}
```

Use this extension to convert UIImage to Data

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Compress UIImage Quality
extension UIImage {
    enum JPEGQuality: CGFloat {
        case lowest  = 0
        case low     = 0.25
        case medium  = 0.5
        case high    = 0.75
        case highest = 1
    }

    /// Returns the data for the specified image in JPEG format.
    /// If the image object’s underlying image data has been purged, calling this function forces that data to be reloaded into memory.
    /// - returns: A data object containing the JPEG data, or nil if there was a problem generating the data. This function may return nil if the image has no data or if the underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported bitmap format.
    func jpeg(_ quality: JPEGQuality) -> Data? {
        return self.jpegData(compressionQuality: quality.rawValue)
    }
}
```

After you have successfully retrieved selected image data, you can perform your tasks to save/upload to your online or local DB.

Comment: OP wrote: _I have successfully implemented an Image Picker in my app - it pulls pictures from the library and you can select specific images._

Comment: He is saying: Now after the user selects the image, I want to store the image to a variable somehow in my code so that I can upload the image to a database.

Comment: Okay, now it's clear, based on additional comments from OP. Just edit your answer and convert `UIImage` to `Data` via `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` / `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with saving the image as NSdata data = image.AsJPEG(1);  Like I currently have in my code?

Answer (score -1):

This answer is an alternative that you might consider instead of using UIImagePicker

Here this function will allow you to get the photos on the library on the phone, so you can use the result of this function which will be an away of `[UIImage]` and store it on a variable I understand you need to do. but to actually check what image what the user to upload you will need to build a CollectionView for example and give the user the option to select the photos to upload, will the user selecting the photos from the collection view you can save the index that you can use to define which pictures to upload.

Note: you can specify the request option: (the delivery mode defines the quality of the image you can use `fastFormat` , `opportunistic` or `highQualityFormat`)

```
requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
```

This is the function just a copy past on your project will do the trick

```
private func getPhotos() -> [UIImage]? {
    
    // Image Array declaration
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    
    // Image manager and specify the request option
    let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
    
    // Sorted by creation date
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    
    // Perform the fetch and appand to Image array
    if let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {
        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {
                imageManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i), targetSize: CGSize(width: 280, height: 280), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { image, error in
                    imageArray.append(image!)
                }
            }
            return imageArray
        } else {
            print("You dont have any photos!")
        }
    }
    
    return nil
}
```